# Will these components work on GHI ChipWorkX?

Tags: embedded, .net-micro-framework

I am trying to implement something using NET MF and was looking for a suitable board.

While I am pretty sure that the FEZ Cobra would do trick, the ChipworkX is just so much better!

So, would these components work with ChipworkX?

http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/12/fez-cobra/#/list/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you'd need to rebuild the firmware with the relevant drivers in order to utilize the hardware.